# Send nested dict or list from a Python script to Rails app via HTTP

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, json, http

I need to send a nested list or dict from a Python script to Ruby on Rails 3 app via HTTP. Ideally, I want to be able to retrieve the object just by using Rails `params[]` in the controller.

I'm new to all this. Could you please tell me how to do this? I've read that formatting the nested list or dict to JSON might be the best way, but I don't know how to send JSON data via HTTP, let alone make the sent data be easily accessible using Rails `params[]`.

Comment: Why do you want to use `params[]` anyways? If your dictionary size is big your shouldn't go for `params[]`. JSON as http-post content is the preferred way.

Comment: Um, how exactly do I do it? A pointer to a resource will be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

It just depends on what kind of request you make. If you do a get request then a simple string formatted like so would work:

```
example.com/controller/action?param1=value&param2=other%20value
```

In Rails this would set `params[:param1]='value'` and params[:param2]='other value'`.

If you want to send json just send it as an HTTP post with the content type 'text/json', and make sure the url you post to ends in `.json`, like so:

```
example.com/controller/action.json
```

That will set the params hash with the same keys and values as your json.

Comment: Do I need to do something in routes.rb or the controller to be able to accept the JSON data? Or do I only have to send JSON via POST request to the appropriate controller action path like in your example above, and it will automagically be accessible via the params hash?